# How do I set the datasource URL in Quarkus to a replicated Postgres database on a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, quarkus, reactive, database-replication

I have a Quarkus application connecting to a Postgres database running on Kubernetes using the Reactive PostgreSQL Client in Quarkus.
The Postgres database is deployed via the Bitnami postgresql Helm chart. This is a subchart of a Helm chart that I use to deploy my Quarkus application.
I set the `readReplicas.replicaCount` for the postgresql Helm chart to more than 1.

In values.yaml of Quarkus application Helm chart:

```yaml
...
postgresql:
    architecture: replication
    readReplicas:
        replicaCount: 2
...
```

This results in a replicated Postgres database (StatefulSet) in Kubernetes with one Pod as primary and two Pods as read replicas:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n myapp
NAME                         READY   STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE
myapp-5cf7f6cdcb-rsdv4       0/1     Init:0/1   0          3m32s
myapp-postgresql-primary-0   1/1     Running    0          3m32s
myapp-postgresql-read-0      1/1     Running    0          3m32s
myapp-postgresql-read-1      1/1     Running    0          3m5s
```

Before I used the replication of the postgres database I just used `myapp-postgresql` as DNS name for the connection URL because there was only one Kubernetes Service called `myapp-postgresql`

Like so, in `application.properties` of Quarkus application:

```
quarkus.datasource.reactive.url: vertx-reactive:postgresql://myapp-postgresql:5432/myapp
```

But now, with the replicated database, there is one Kubernetes Service for the primary pod and the read replica pods each:

```
$ kubectl get svc -n myapp
NAME                          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
myapp                         ClusterIP   10.43.216.204   <none>        8080/TCP   5m21s
myapp-postgresql-primary      ClusterIP   10.43.249.106   <none>        5432/TCP   5m21s
myapp-postgresql-read         ClusterIP   10.43.223.28    <none>        5432/TCP   5m21s
```

Which Kubernetes Service shall I use for the connection string?
It seems senseful to me to use the `read`-Service if I only query the database and the `primary`-Service to write to the database but how am I suppose to differentiate between the two in the `application.properties` file?

Comment: Just a hint. YugabyteDB is a cloud native database on the top of PostgreSQL. For example, it has a built-in load balanced cluster management. This [tutorial](https://www.yugabyte.com/blog/integrating-yugabytedb-with-spring-boot-quarkus-micronaut/) describes how to integrate Quarkus, Spring or Micronaut application to Yugabyte. It's worth a try I guess.